# Backbone, routes, link

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes

Stuck on a tricky one for me... Backbone based Routes controller and desired affect not being achieved.

I need to grab the URL based only upon the first part of it and direct to a route on any one of the possibilities.

The JS

```
routes: {
        "": "home",
        "home": "home",
        "myaccount": "myaccount",
        "entry-1": "entry"

    },
```

I am trying to get the routes to go to entry on the occasion that ANY entry-number is present in the link.

Example: entry-1: entry, entry-2: entry, entry-3: entry and so on, but without having to print all of the possible numbers.

Is there a way to achieve this?

---

Edited version: got it working by using a condition i had never heard of before!

actions: seemed to do the job and the *.

```
     routes: {

    "*actions:entry": "entry"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Backbone routes work as Regexs so you can do;

```
initialize: function() {
  this.route(/entry-([0-9]+)/, "entry");
},

entry: function(number) {
  // router page logic
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. That looks close to what i require, but that has broken the code. I have added that and for some reason responds by stopping the routes from working, they all show.

Comment: @muistooshort Whoops, of course I'd done it wrong. It was late :)